# Validate url.format(urlObject)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, types, schema

I am curious about the [NodeJS URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html). Specifically, the `url.format(urlObject)` method. I would like to create a function that validates an `urlObject` before calling format, and throws a TypeError if any of the object key/value pairs are invalid, or "extra" (not present in the spec).

Is there some way, outside of TypeScript typings, to achieve this?

Comment: even typescript would not "validate" those objects. It will only prevent calling attributes on an object whose are not included in the given type

Comment: @messerbill It wouldn't compile. You understood my question.

Comment: it would compile due to the url will be set during the runtime...otherwise i missunderstood your question. I though you try to "inspect" the value of `urlObject` and validate it - expecting that some invalid data could be sent during the runtime

Answer (score 0):

You will have a hard time doing that because when you create a `URL` instance:

```js
u = new URL('http://example.com/');
```

both `Object.keys(u)` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(u)` will return an empty array and even `JSON.stringify(u)` will not help you here as it results in a single top level string, not a JSON representation of the object.

So you will not be able to able to check for any extra fields easily, unless you manually parse the output of `util.format(u)` or something like that - but you would still need to check for object keys (including non-enumerable properties) to validate other objects that are not an instance of `URL`.

So the most reasonable solution would be to check if `u instanceof URL` and if it's true then trust that it's fine, but if it's false then check for the specific properties.

But keep in mind that the `url.format()` doesn't need an actual `URL` instance, e.g. those two lines have the same effect:

```js
a = url.format(new URL('http://example.com/'));
b = url.format({ protocol: 'http', host: 'example.com', pathname: '/' });
// a === b
```

To validate if the `URL` instance (or any other object) has the following properties and they are strings, like it should be in the `URL` instance, you can use something like:

```js
const k = [
  'href',
  'origin',
  'protocol',
  'username',
  'password',
  'host',
  'hostname',
  'port',
  'pathname',
  'search',
  'hash',
];

const validUrl = u => k.filter(k => typeof u[k] === 'string').length === k.length;
```

This will return `true` for normal `URL` instances:

```js
u = new URL('http://example.com/');
console.log(validUrl(u));
```

but also for other objects, if they have all of the required fields.
But keep in mind that the `url.format()` doesn't require all of the fields, as you can see on the example above, so that way you would reject some of the valuse that would be perfectly fine for `url.format()` like:

```js
u = { protocol: 'http', host: 'example.com', pathname: '/' };
```

To sum it up:

Real `URL` instances don't show you what properties do they have so you will not easily test for extra properties - but I would not advice to do that anyway because your code will break if the `URL` ever gets extended with new properties which can happen in the future.

To see if it has all the required (in your opinion - not necessarily in the opinion of `url.format()`!) properties, you can write a simple validator function but then you will not be able to omit empty properties like `username` if there is none and you would have to pass empty strings for all empty properties explicitly, if you want to be able to use `URL`-like objects that are otherwise compatible with `url.format()`.

Maybe you want to test just some of the fields like protocol, host and pathname but then you have to handle that `url.format()` will take either `host` or `hostname`, preferring `host` if both are available etc.

You can also try some hack like this:

```js
const testUrl = u => {
  try {
    new URL(url.format(u));
  } catch (e) {
    throw new TypeError('your error message');
  }
};
```

and have a function that experimentally test if a given value works with `url.format()` giving a URL parsable by `new URL()` like this:

```js
testUrl(new URL('http://example.com')); // ok
testUrl({host: 'example.com', protocol: 'http'}); // ok
testUrl({host: 'example.com'}); // throws a TypeError
```

Now in your function that calls `url.format(urlObject)` all you have to do is add: `testUrl(urlObject)` in the line before and it will throw exceptions that you describe.

All in all, this is a tricky question. You can do it in many ways but all have some drawbacks. The `URL` instances are actually quite strange and even Joi breaks on them!

For example:

```js
!joi.object({ host: joi.string().required() }).validate({ host: 'example.com' }).error;
// returns true

!joi.object({ host: joi.string().required() }).validate({ nohost: 'example.com' }).error
// returns false

!joi.object({ host: joi.string().required() }).validate(new URL('http://example.com/')).error;
// this throws an exception!
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
// WTF???
```

If even Joi cannot validate `URL` instances then they are not easy to validate.

Hopefully some of the examples above will do what you need.